# Configure ClientCredential of IdentityModel using values retrieved from Cloud Foundry CredHub

Tags: .net-5, identitymodel, steeltoe

Short Problem Statement:
How to get value from Cloud Foundry CredHub to be used inside `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`?

Existing Condition:
Let's say that I have a class called `SystemConfig` for holding configuration values. I use a combination of json file and dotnet secrets in 'Development' stage for storing those values, and they can be retrieved via

```
services.Configure<SystemConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("GLOBAL"));
```

In 'SIT' stage, I use Pivotal Cloud Foundry to host the application and a combination of ConfigServer - CredHub for storing configuration values. Values from CredHub can be retrieved inside `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` via

```
var credhub = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<CloudFoundryServicesOptions>>().Value.Services["credhub"].First(x => x.Name.Equals("credhub-instance"));
var sysConfig = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<SystemConfig>>().Value;
sysConfig.SAMPLE_A = credhub.Credentials[nameof(sysConfig.SAMPLE_A)].Value;
```

The problem arises when I need to configure Access Token Management from `IdentityModel.AspNetCore` inside `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAccessTokenManagement(x => 
{
     x.Client.Clients.Add("key_sample", new IdentityModel.Client.ClientCredentialsTokenRequest()
     {
         Address = "sysConfig.SAMPLE_A",
         ClientId = "taken from sysConfig as well",
         ClientSecret = "taken from sysConfig as well"
     });
});
```

The method `AddAccessTokenManagement` can only be used inside `ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)` but at the same time I don't have values from CredHub yet because they are retrieved inside `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`.
Usage of `services.BuildServiceProvider()` is not recommended as well since it will create additional copy of Singleton services that might lead to unexpected bugs.

So the question boils down to :

- Can we retrieve CredHub value inside `ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)` ?
- If it is not possible, then can we somehow set `AddAccessTokenManagement` inside `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to the intricacies of IdentityModel here, and at a glance I don't see anything that makes this easy from that side, but I have a solution that should work that uses Steeltoe Connectors by customizing the way `SsoServiceInfo` can be located.

Ideally Steeltoe would bind these credentials to `SsoServiceInfo` automatically, but there isn't currently anything built in that makes that connection. This code will work to retrieve the service info by the time we're done here:

```cs
services.AddAccessTokenManagement(x =>
{
    var creds = Configuration.GetServiceInfo<SsoServiceInfo>("credhub-instance");
    x.Client.Clients.Add("key_sample", new IdentityModel.Client.ClientCredentialsTokenRequest()
    {
        Address = creds.AuthDomain,
        ClientId = creds.ClientId,
        ClientSecret = creds.ClientSecret
    });
});
```

In order to enable the above code, we'll need to add a custom `ServiceInfoFactory` that can bind your credhub service instance to `SsoServiceInfo`:

```cs
using Steeltoe.Connector.Services;
using Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration;

public class AuthServiceInfoFactory : ServiceInfoFactory
{
    public AuthServiceInfoFactory()
        : base(new Tags("credhub"), "credhub")
         // second param here for url scheme won't actually be used but can't be empty
    {
    }

    public override IServiceInfo Create(Service binding)
    {
        // these methods ship with Steeltoe, but look for "client_id" and "client_secret" - customize as desired
        var clientId = GetClientIdFromCredentials(binding.Credentials);
        var clientSecret = GetClientSecretFromCredentials(binding.Credentials);
        var authDomain = GetStringFromCredentials(binding.Credentials, "auth_domain");

        return new SsoServiceInfo(binding.Name, clientId, clientSecret, authDomain);
    }
}
```

Next add the `ServiceInfoFactoryAssembly` attribute to `AssemblyInfo.cs` so Steeltoe can find your new factory:

```cs
using Steeltoe.Connector;

[assembly: ServiceInfoFactoryAssembly]
```

Also, Connectors build on the CloudFoundry Configuration Provider, so be sure you've added it to your host builder or configuration builder with something like this:

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .AddCloudFoundryConfiguration();
```

Finally, please note that as of v3.0, Steeltoe won't recognize `vcap:services` unless `vcap:application` has been set, so you might want use this configuration format for non-CloudFoundry environments:

```json
  "services": {
    "credhub": [{
      "name": "credhub-instance",
      "credentials": {
        "Client_Id": "myClientId",
        "Client_Secret": "myClientSecret"
      },
      "tags": ["credhub"]
    }]
  }
```